# C++ - how to convert between types that are only known at runtime

Tags: c++, types, type-conversion

I wish to design a type-safe NxM *cross-connect*. This is a mechanism that allows any of N function outputs to be connected to any of M inputs. Or to put it another way, to connect the return value a function (from a set of functions) with a parameter of another. A key aspect is that these *connections* must be configurable at runtime. The main issue I have is that the *type* of the inputs will differ from the outputs depending on each connection.

Let's say at some arbitrary point in the program I want to connect the return value of `float foo()` to the parameter `val` in `void bar(double val)`.

I currently have two parameterised classes representing the inputs and outputs, named `Source<T>` and `Dest<U>`. T & U are expected to be float, double, bool, int, unsigned int, etc. I have a heterogeneous collection of `Source<T>` instances, some double, some float, some int, some bool. There is also a heterogeneous collection of `Dest<U>` instances, also some double, some float, some int, some bool. Sometimes T and U are the same type. For more context, these instances are all associated with unique names, allowing the higher level system to say "now please connect source::foo with dest::bar", or "remove the association between source::red and dest::blue".

In the previous example, at compile time, the type of the return value from `foo()` is known by the programmer to be float and can be specified in source, so a `Source<float>` can be instantiated and associated with this function. And the type of the parameter to `bar()` is also known to be double so a `Dest<double>` can be instantiated and associated with this function (with a `std::function` wrapper). Then at **runtime** `Source<float>` can be associated with the `Dest<double>` and  communicate the value to `Dest<double>` via a polymorphic pointer (through an inherited interface that all `Dest<U>` instances share). `Dest<double>` will then invoke the function `bar()` using the `std::function` wrapper.

So, at runtime, the aim is to associate any `Source` with any `Dest`, for arbitrary duration, and to re-associate at any time. So I need a way to create a function that can convert a type `T` only known at runtime into another type `U` also only known at runtime.

To complicate things slightly, the return and parameter values may actually be arrays of arbitrary size. For example, `foo()` may return a `float[32]` array, but `bar()` may expect a `double[8]` array (perhaps throwing away 3 of every 4 values). My idea is that this "Bridge" mechanism would handle this, once it can handle the type conversion.

Frankly, I'm not really seeing how to implement this. If the Source-to-Dest associations were fixed at compile time, I could write a family of templated `Bridge<T,U>` functions that would do the conversion, but because this all needs to happen at runtime I don't think that's the answer.

Is it the best approach to write a generic `Bridge<T,U>` function, then create some sort of dynamic dispatch mechanism to select the appropriate one at runtime based on T and U? How would I go about determining the types of T and U at runtime in order to pick the correct instance of `Bridge`? I'd also want to catch the case where T and U are the same type and therefore avoid any unnecessary conversion (as an optimisation).

Or is there a better way to accomplish what I want to do?

Comment: can't you do a dynamic_cast<type>(variable)

Comment: **Code** exhibiting a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) will go a *long* way in getting feedback on this question.

Comment: @WhozCraig: I'm working on some examples so I'll see what I can do to post something.

Comment: @GeraldSv: I was under the impression that dynamic_cast only works with pointers and references?

Comment: Primitive types are relatively easy.  The hard part is non-primitive types -- ie, a type `Egg` that converts to `Chicken`.  Some questions: can you have an enumeration every input and output type?  Can you round-trip via serialization?  Can you write up boilerplate code for each type that you add to the system? (ie, before you can add a type `T` as a `Dest<T>`, you have to register the type `T` somewhere).  Can this registration be compile-time deterministic?  Or are you adding 3rd party DLLs with their own custom functions that produce `Dest<Egg>` and `Source<Chicken>`?

Comment: I'm actually mostly concerned with conversion between arrays of floats and doubles, with ints a secondary concern. This is part of a numerical system that is passing around numerical scalars and arrays. The main problem I have with my example attempt so far is in defining a base class for the linkage between the Source and Dest, as the types on both sides are necessary to properly define the 'send' function. I wonder if it might be worth looking into packing the values into a "type anonymous" char array and reinterpreting it on receipt.

Comment: One idea I'd like to try, but I'm having trouble working out how to do it, is to create and select at runtime from a set of functions: float-array-to-double-array, double-array-to-int-array, etc, but I'm not sure how one can query the type of a Source or Dest (i.e. T and U) at runtime - something like typeid() on a typedef, where the typedef is defined inside the template?

Comment: I may resort to simply representing everything as a `double`, and then  the std::function should handle the conversion down to float, int, etc when calling the final function. Doesn't help with 64-bit integers but I'm not planning to use them anyway.