# How to dynamically determine the types used to parameterise a template and compare them

Tags: c++, types, type-conversion

If one creates a class template based on one or more type parameters, how would one query these types at runtime?

For example:

```
template <typename T>
class Foo {
 public:
  typedef T TypeT;

  Foo() {}

  // assume i is in range
  void set(size_t i, T value) { store[i] = value; }
  T get(size_t i) { return store[i]; }

  void fast_copy(T* dest) { memcpy(dest, store, 100 * size_of(T)); }

  // ugly public data member
  T store[100];
};


void main() {
  Foo<double> fd;
  Foo<int> fi;

  // this is not C++!
  if (fd::TypeT == fi::TypeT) {

    // do a fast copy since the types match
    fd.fast_copy(fi.store);

  } else {

    // do a slower item by copy since the types don't match
    // and let the runtime perform the type conversion:
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
      fi.set(i, static_cast<fd::TypeT>(fd.get(i)));
    }
  }
}
```

The reason I want to do this is because I have runtime objects that contain either arrays of floats, doubles or ints, and I want to copy them to an array of a different type, but I don't know what those types will be as they are determined at runtime. In the above example, the types used to instantiate fi and fd are known, but in the full example fi and fd would be references to a polymorphic class that could be containers of an array of any basic numerical type.

This mechanism is intended to be a runtime configurable *bridge* between a set of functions that return arrays of floats, doubles or ints, and another set that requires arrays of floats, doubles, or ints, and the types may or may not be the same on both sides of the bridge. The bridge is non-trivial and does a few other things, but needs to take an array (or a container of an array) of one type in, and produce array an (or a container of an array) of another type at the other end, in cases where the types are the same and also where they are not.

Note: this is related to [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15606632) of mine and will replace it if this one makes more sense.

EDIT: here's a bit more info on what I'm trying to do.

I have a system that *on one side* consists of a set of functions that *return* numerical results. Some return a single float or double, some a single int, some modify (hence 'return') an array of floats, or doubles, or ints. There's a whole bunch of them. I want to associate each one (well, actually, just the returned data, the functions don't matter) with something I call a "Source" object - this might be `Source<T>`, where T is the numerical type. Although I might need `SourceScalar<T>` and `SourceVector<T>` to handle single values or arrays. Anyway, this object is the entry point to the "Bridge". Each `Source<T>` object is stored in a heterogenous collection of Source objects, and referenced by a unique "Source Key". For example, one such Source-associated function might return an array of 32 floats representing the latest output from a wavetable oscillator. Another might return an array of 32 doubles representing a peak detector output over 32 samples.

*On the other side* of the system I have yet another set of functions. These all take numerical values as parameters. Some require a single float or double, some a single int, some require arrays of the same. There's a whole bunch of these too. I have something I call a "Dest" object - `Dest<T>`, or maybe `DestScalar<T>`, `DestVector<T>` as above.  This object stores a std::function wrapper that is tied to one of these functions, so that it can invoke the function when necessary. Each Dest object is stored in a hetereogenous collection of Dest objects, and referenced by a unique "Dest Key". For example, one such function might be a digital filter that expects to receive arrays of size 32, but of doubles not floats.

Now, at runtime, a higher-level system (actually controlled by a user) is required to arbitrarily associate any Source with any Dest. The user provides the two keys - source and dest - and the system 'connects' the data on one side with the function on the other. So in the example above, it might try to connect the 32-float array from the wavetable oscillator to the 32-double array parameter of the digital filter. At any time this association might be removed, too. If the 32-double array from the peak detector is connected to the 32-double array parameter of the digital filter, then it would want the transfer/copy to be as fast as possible because the arrays are of the same type.

**EDIT 2:** here is some code that compiles and is the simplest case I can construct that creates two collections of Source and Dest objects, and dynamically attempts to 'connect' them. The first two calls to `source_collection[1]->set(...)` work correctly, but the second two do not, and end up calling the BaseDest base class member function `set_item` rather than the one in `Dest<T>`. This also uses the observation that typeid() returns a static pointer if the type queried is the same, and compares the *values* of these pointers to determine that the type matches. This is probably unsafe, might be best to just use enums instead.

*This all feels very horrible to me - there must be a better way?*

```
#include <vector>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <cassert>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>

class Source;    // fwd
class BaseDest;  // fwd

typedef boost::shared_ptr<Source>   SourcePtr;
typedef boost::shared_ptr<BaseDest> BaseDestPtr;

// target function that takes an array of doubles
void target_func_vd(double *array, size_t len) {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    assert(array[i] == i);
  }
}

// target function that takes an array of floats
void target_func_vf(float *array, size_t len) {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    assert(array[i] == i);
  }
}

// base class for Dest
class BaseDest {
public:
  BaseDest() {}
  virtual ~BaseDest() {}

  virtual void set(float *array, size_t len)  { /* not implemented, but can't be pure */ };
  virtual void set(double *array, size_t len) { /* not implemented, but can't be pure */ };

  virtual void set_item(size_t index, double item) { /* not implemented, but can't be pure */ };
  virtual void set_item(size_t index, float item) { /* not implemented, but can't be pure */ };
  virtual void finished(size_t len) = 0;

  virtual const std::type_info* get_type_info() const = 0;
private:
};

template <typename T>
class DestVector : public BaseDest {
public:
  typedef boost::function<void (T *, size_t)> Callable;

  explicit DestVector(Callable callable) : callable_(callable) { }

  virtual void set(T *array, size_t len) { callable_(array, len); }
  virtual void set_item(size_t index, T item) { buffer_[index] = item; }
  virtual void finished(size_t len) { callable_(buffer_, len); }

  virtual const std::type_info* get_type_info() const { return &typeid(T); };
private:
  Callable callable_;
  T buffer_[256];
};

// 'set' is overloaded by array type
class Source {
public:
  Source() {}
  void connect(const BaseDestPtr& dest) { dest_ = dest; }

  void set(float *array, size_t len) {
    if (dest_->get_type_info() == &typeid(double)) {
      // convert to double
      for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        dest_->set_item(i, array[i]);  // calls the base member function
      }
      dest_->finished(len);
    } else if (dest_->get_type_info() == &typeid(float)) {
      dest_->set(array, len);
    }
  }

  void set(double *array, size_t len) {
    if (dest_->get_type_info() == &typeid(float)) {
      // convert to float
      for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        dest_->set_item(i, array[i]);  // calls the base member function
      }
      dest_->finished(len);
    } else if (dest_->get_type_info() == &typeid(double)) {
      dest_->set(array, len);
    }
  }

private:
  BaseDestPtr dest_;
};


void main() {

  // test arrays
  float float_array[256];
  for (size_t i = 0; i < 256; ++i) {
    float_array[i] = static_cast<float>(i);
  }

  double double_array[256];
  for (size_t i = 0; i < 256; ++i) {
    double_array[i] = static_cast<double>(i);
  }

  // collection of Sources
  std::vector<SourcePtr> source_collection;

  SourcePtr s0(new Source());
  source_collection.push_back(s0);

  SourcePtr s1(new Source());
  source_collection.push_back(s1);


  // collection of Dests
  std::vector<BaseDestPtr> dest_collection;

  BaseDestPtr t0(new DestVector<float>(&target_func_vf));
  dest_collection.push_back(t0);

  BaseDestPtr t1(new DestVector<double>(&target_func_vd));
  dest_collection.push_back(t1);


  // create and invoke connections
  source_collection[0]->connect(dest_collection[0]);
  source_collection[0]->set(float_array, 256);  // this should end up passing float_array to target_func_vf, and it does

  source_collection[0]->connect(dest_collection[1]);
  source_collection[0]->set(double_array, 256); // this should end up passing double_array to target_func_vd, and it does

  source_collection[1]->connect(dest_collection[0]);
  source_collection[1]->set(double_array, 256); // this should end up passing double_array to target_func_vf, but it doesn't

  source_collection[1]->connect(dest_collection[1]);
  source_collection[1]->set(float_array, 256); // this should end up passing float_array to target_func_vd, but it doesn't
}
```

Comment: Here you can use std::is_same, or if you want runtime - typeid(T).

Comment: You would overload the copying for same and different types. <What is `U` BTW?

Comment: If you want to copy any of A, B, C into any of A, B, C, you need to have nine separate pieces of code. It makes no sense to query types at runtine as all types are known already at compile time (except when there is inheritance but this is not your case). Try to come up with a use case where you genuinely need to query types (hint: not really possible; at most you need a compile-time query if you are writing a template).

Comment: Of course your 9 pieces of code may be instantiations of the same template, so you don't necessarily have to write them all by hand.

Comment: Sorry, U was meant to be T. I originally had it as U but changed it to T and missed a couple of instances - my mistake. I've edited the question.

Comment: @n.m. sure, I don't mind having nine pieces of code (manually written or templated), I just need some way to select the right one at the right time, dynamically.

Comment: @ForEver: how would I query the type ID of the parameter of Foo? Could I do typeid(f::TypeT)?

Comment: @meowsqueak yes, you can.http://liveworkspace.org/code/21hWRX$1

Comment: Show an example where you need to select something dynamically. So far you only have code that has everything known statically, which is not an accident.

Comment: @ForEveR: ah, but in your example code, ic is a typedef (i.e. type) not a variable. What I have to deal with is a polymorphic pointer or reference to a Dest<T>, and I need to find out what T was when it was instantiated. I'm leaning towards storing typeid(*this) inside Dest<T> (and all the problems that will cause).

Comment: @n.m. I have updated the question with some code doing something dynamically. It's not pretty, but it does compile. It doesn't, however, work properly. Details in the question/code.

Comment: OK now that you've introduced inheritance you need run-time type selection. But avoid the switch-by-typeinfo anti-idiom, C++ has a superior mechanism for this and it is called virtual functions. In your case the visitor pattern a.k.a. double dispatch should work well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use overloads. Add this to your class

```
void copy(T & dest)
{
   fast_copy(&dest):
}

template<class U>
void copy(U & dest)
{
   for (size_t i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
      dest.set(i, static_cast<TypeT>(get(i)));
}
```

PS: more c++ way is to define copy-constructor or assignment operator

EDIT: If you want dynamic mke things more polymorphic

```
struct BaseDest
{
   virtual void assign(const double * v, size_t cnt) = 0;
   virtual void assign(const float * v, size_t cnt) = 0;
//etc
}

template<class T>
struct DestImpl
{
   void assign(const double * v, size_t cnt)
   {
       assign_impl(v, cnt);
   }
   void assign(const float * v, size_t cnt)
   {
       assign_impl(v, cnt);
   }

   template<class U>
   void assign_impl(const U * v, size_t cnt)
   {
      for (size_t i = 0; i < cnt; ++i) {
         set(i, static_cast<T>(v[i])));
   }

   template<>
   void assign_impl<T>(const T * v, size_t cnt)
   {
      fast_copy(v, cnt);
   }
//stuff
}

struct Source
{
//blah
   template<class T>
   void set(const T * v, size_t cnt)
   {
     dest_->set(v, cnt);
   }

//blah
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is all static, isn't it? What I need is a way to select the right version of `copy` at runtime, based on a dynamic association between two objects. Please see the code I've posted as "EDIT 2".

Comment: Thanks, that looks straightforward - is this similar to the so-called double-dispatch mentioned by n.m. in the question comments? Or would that involve a DestImpl object being given a `Source<T>` object and calling an overloaded member function based on the type of the `Source`? BTW, DestImpl is meant to publicly inherit from BaseDest, is that right?

Comment: I'm running into a problem here - seems that it's not legal to specialise a function template inside a class/struct. Would the solution be to move the assign_impl specialisations into non-member functions (and make them friend if they need to access data members of DestImpl)?

Comment: Referring to http://stackoverflow.com/a/1757845/143397, I thought I'd found a solution to this, but my compiler (clang) warns me that the template parameter can never be deduced.

Comment: I've split this off into a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15648681/143397

Comment: @meowsqueak You could specialise it outside struct definition, using `DestImpl::...`, or try (due to impossibility to partialy specialise free template function) make a template helper class with non-template static function